# Disable caching with contextual Google Gadget

Tags: google-gadget

I'm having trouble loading my updated XML for a contextual gadget in gmail. I was reading through the [Google Gadgets FAQ](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/faq), and it is stated that the XML files are cached for a few hours. 
I've been searching for a while on how to get around this and found a few solutions such as:

- Add a nocache=1 (or something close to that) to the querystring
- Add anything to the querystring
- Use the "My Gadget" gadget to disable caching.

None of these solutions work for me, and I'm suspecting it's because none of them are newer than 2010 and things tend to change. Has anyone else run into this issue recently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not **&nocache=1** but **&nogadgetcache=1** that must be added;

make sure you append this before the # in the URL !

from the docs :

**Changes to gadget don't show up immediately.**

Gmail is probably using a cached version of the gadget. Changes to gadgets can take some time to be reflected because of caching. Solution: Make sure you include the flag **&nogadgetcache=1** in the URL when you start Gmail to test your gadgets. This flag ensures that any changes you make to gadgets will show up in your Gmail account immediately. If you reference external resources in your gadget, such as JS or CSS files located on external servers, those resources are still subject to caching.

https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets

Comment: first koma's solution worked (I gave him +1) but now it doesn't work any more :( Now as a workaroud I add one more query tag like: &nogadgetcache=1&version=2 and I always increase the number of version